# Weird question: elements of eigenvector as kinetic and potential energies

Tags: energy, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, linear-algebra

Assume we have $N$ particles each having some potential and kinetic energies. Denote the sum of kinetic energy as $\sum_i T_i = T$ and the sum of potential energy as $\sum_i V_i= V$. This is a closed system, so $L+T=C$ is a constant.

Now we construct a vector whose elements are the square roots of kinetic energies and potential energies: $[\sqrt{T_1},\cdots,\sqrt{T_N},\sqrt{V_1},\cdots,\sqrt{V_N}]$. The square of its L2 norm is $C$, no matter what the state of the system is. Since the norm is always preserved, this is like an eigenvector of some matrix $M$ which is somehow parameterized by the state of the system.

I know this is very weird and vague, but is there a formulation in the field of physics that utilizes an idea like this? If so, how would $M$ be parameterized? I am familiar with treating an eigenvalue like energy, but not this.

EDIT: Just realized that obviously if $M$ is rank 1, then $M$ is parameterized as $M=vv^T$ where $v=[\sqrt{T_1},\cdots,\sqrt{T_N},\sqrt{V_1},\cdots,\sqrt{V_N}]$. I wonder if there is a way to make sense of $M$ with a rank greater than 1...

Comment: How is the norm C when the components are square roots of energy?

Comment: I meant to write "square of L2 norm is C". Corrected in the post.